# Dynamic declaration of a component - ADF

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf

My JDev version is *11.1.1.7.0*.

Today I want to know if it is possible to dynamically declare a component.
By this I mean, when you are binding a component to a java bean, can you have some logic like:

```
#{pageFlowScope.someCondition eq 'true' ? pageFlowScope.ManagedBean.propertity : pageFlowScope.OtherManagedBean.propertity }
```

When editing the field (Binding property of a component) it only allows you to enter a Bean and choose between its properties  .

I really need to be able to choose between 2 properties in runtime, based on a condition for this binding property of a component .

Any further explanation, please ask.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this may work, depending on how #{pageFlowScope.someCondition} changes the value. If the value changes during a request that renders the component, you may get inconsistency.

You can also reference components directly on pageFlowScope without using a bean necessary, something like:

```
#{pageFlowScope.mySelectOneChoice}
```

Comment: The scenario is: I am putting the someCondition on the pageFlowScope. This condition was gathered in a pagePhaseListener beforePhase, before the rendering of a page. Then depending on this someCondition, I need to declare the component to a Java Bean, either mine or some 3rd party's. It is also to mention that I'm doing this in a Customization project.

Comment: As long as the value of "someCondition" is set during first page load and it doesn't change while in this page, it should work.